# SwiftUI VStack frame alignment adds unexpected extra space above child content

Tags: swiftui

I start with the following code:

```
        VStack {
            HStack {
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color("dark_background"))
        }.frame(maxWidth : .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
```

which looks like this:

[image: correct size]

After aligning top with the following code:

```
        VStack {
            HStack {
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color("dark_background"))
        }.frame(maxWidth : .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
```

It adds a few extra pixels to the top of the HStack

[image: extra pixels]

How do I remove the extra pixels and align to the top at the same time?

The only thing I can think to do is manually set a fixed height but I do not like this solution.

Interestingly, it does not add extra pixels when center or bottom aligning, only for top aligning.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. What versions of macOS and Xcode are you doing this on?

Comment: It might only be happening for native desktop applications, Xcode: Version 15.2 (15C500b), macOS: 14.0 (23A344)

Comment: I am indeed targeting native macOS (as opposed to designed for iPad or Mac Catalyst), though I am on Xcode 15.0 and macOS 14.1.1. I suspect the reason is the old macOS version.